# How to stop a timer at a specific time in java?

Tags: java, timer

I have made a timer in java that starts but I do not know how to stop it. Below is my code for the timer.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            label1.setText("Hello");        
    }

});
timer.start();
```

I want to add in few other texts when the timer reaches 500 and then stop the timer when it reaches 1000.

Answer (score 3):

> "How to stop a timer at a specific time in java?"

Just do this. Increment the count each fire of the timer event, if the count is at a certain point, then stop the timer, else set the text to the count

```
int count = 0;
JLabel label = new JLabel(String.valueOf(count));
public Constructor() {
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (count >= 100) {
                ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
            } else {
                label.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                count++;
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use multiple timers. A better approach though is to use something like a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` `ExecutorService` and you can then schedule as many `Runnable`s as you like to be executed with whatever timings you like...